# Reading File of Certain Sequence

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In VB.NET; I am trying to read text file (say 5th text file in folder);
My code below read all files and write down the values of LAST file only:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MekdamFolder As String
    MekdamFolder = Application.ExecutablePath.Remove(Application.ExecutablePath.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
    Dim MekdamFile As String
    Dim MekdamFiles As String() = Directory.GetFiles(MekdamFolder, "*.txt")
    For Each MekdamFile In MekdamFiles
    Next
    If System.IO.File.Exists(MekdamFile) Then
        IO.File.OpenText(MekdamFile)
        TextBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MekdamFile)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("MekdamFile Missing")
    End If
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(MekdamFile)
    Dim lineArray As New ArrayList(1000)
    For zzzz As Integer = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
        lineArray.Add(lines(zzzz))
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(lines(zzzz) & vbCrLf)
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, last, fifth - the filenamess are returned to you in an arbitrary order.  todays, first may be tomorrows tenth.

```
' this loop does nothing, except leave Mekdam set to the last file
For Each MekdamFile In MekdamFiles
   ' add code here to Exit For when MekdamFile 
   ' equals something meaningful
Next

' this can currently only edit the last file found due to the above loop.
If System.IO.File.Exists(MekdamFile) Then
    IO.File.OpenText(MekdamFile)
    TextBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(MekdamFile)
Else
....
```

You'd be better off looking for a specific file or getting it from the user.

Comment: I know that; thanks; My question was: How to edit specific text file; like the 4th or 5th????

Comment: count the elements in `MekdamFiles` and set `MekdamFile` accordingly: `MekdamFile = MekdamFiles(4)` or `MekdamFile = MekdamFiles(NumOfFiles - 5)`  **instead of** the loop.  you also do not need a text box to add lines to a file

Comment: @Abbasq1999 wrong, your question is, "Reading File of Certain Sequence". Your trying to read and write to a file it seems, but where's your question and specifically where's the problem at? Frankly you haven't asked a question, but said what you are doing. That doesn't help us when trying to help you, please clarify more.

Comment: Plutonix; Thanks a lot; the answer for my question is to add "MekdamFile = MekdamFiles(4) or MekdamFile = MekdamFiles(NumOfFiles - 5)"  instead of the loop. Thanks Plutonix; +1 and "accept".

Comment: no problem, good luck. DO keep in mind the order is arbitrary